# PHP Order Array based on lowest value of nested array, and then greatest difference

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array such as:

```
$stock_updates = [
    'sku1234' => [
        'current_stock' => [
            'id1' => 6,
            'id2' => 23,
            'id3' => 90,
            'id4' => 61,
        ],
        'actual_stock' => 400,
    ],
    'sku5678' => [
        'current_stock' => [
            'id1' => 3,
            'id2' => 3,
            'id3' => 4,
            'id4' => 11,
        ],
        'actual_stock' => 0,
    ],
    'sku9012' => [
        'current_stock' => [
            'id1' => 1000,
            'id2' => 1,
            'id3' => 56,
            'id4' => 234,
        ],
        'actual_stock' => 100,
    ],
    'sku3456' => [
        'current_stock' => [
            'id1' => 0,
            'id2' => 0,
            'id3' => 1,
            'id4' => 0,
        ],
        'actual_stock' => 200,
    ],
    'sku1123' => [
        'current_stock' => [
            'id1' => 10,
            'id2' => 50,
            'id3' => 234,
            'id4' => 61,
        ],
        'actual_stock' => 5,
    ],
];
```

I want to sort this array under the following criteria, foreach `sku***` key, find the lowest value in the `current_stock` key. With that value first check if there is stock, and check if the actual stock is 0. On a match this would be given the highest priority. Secondly if the `current_stock` key's lowest value is 0 and the `actual_stock` is greater than 0, this data would have second priority. Finally for all other keys, work out the difference between the `actual_stock` and the lowest `current_stock` value. With this difference order by highest difference to lowest.

A visual example of what the above array would look like:

```
$stock_updates_ordered = [
    // Items are showing stock when there is 0 stock - highest priority
    'sku5678' => [
        'current_stock' => [
            'id1' => 3,
            'id2' => 3,
            'id3' => 4,
            'id4' => 11,
        ],
        'actual_stock' => 0,
        'priority' => PHP_INT_MAX, // Highest priority
    ],
    // Items are in stock but the lowest amount is less than available stock, next priority
    'sku1123' => [
        'current_stock' => [
            'id1' => 10,
            'id2' => 50,
            'id3' => 234,
            'id4' => 61,
        ],
        'actual_stock' => 5,
        'priority' => PHP_INT_MAX - 5, // Next highest priority
    ],
    // Items are showing out of stock, but there is stock available, next priority
    'sku3456' => [
        'current_stock' => [
            'id1' => 0,
            'id2' => 0,
            'id3' => 1,
            'id4' => 0,
        ],
        'actual_stock' => 200,
        'priority' => PHP_INT_MAX - 10, // Next highest priority
    ],
    // Items are in stock, but the highest stock discrepancy is 394 (400 - 6) - next priority, based on lowest stock value compared to actual stock value
    'sku1234' => [
        'current_stock' => [
            'id1' => 6,
            'id2' => 23,
            'id3' => 90,
            'id4' => 61,
        ],
        'actual_stock' => 400,
        'priority' => 394, // Priority difference between actual stock and current stock, ordered by largest difference
    ],
    // Items are in stock but the highest stock discrepancy is 99 (100 - 1) - next priority
    'sku9012' => [
        'current_stock' => [
            'id1' => 1000,
            'id2' => 1,
            'id3' => 56,
            'id4' => 234,
        ],
        'actual_stock' => 100,
        'priority' => 99,
    ],
];
```

**Note** the `priority` key is optional, and I have added this for a visual representation of weighting. The end result can either have this priority key, or discard it.

I am guessing this approach is best to use `array_column`, `array_reduce` and `array_filter` however I'm struggling to combine these rules. Average array length is 500. Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: As a good practice and a first step, can you share the function to compare A and B? It should return -1 if A is higher priority and +1 if B is higher priority. Then you can `usort` using that.

Comment: What happens when `actual_stock` is non-zero, but is still less than the minimum value in `current_stock`? Your rules don't mention this, and the only example where the `actual_stock` is less than the minimum, is the special case where `actual_stock` is 0...

Comment: @trincot thanks for raising this, this should be accounted for. I'll update my question to include this use case

Comment: But there can be many different cases where `actual_stock` is less than the minimum among `current_stock`. How should they be ordered relative to each other? Should the difference be used in some way? Are you sure that a zero `actual_stock` with the minimum among `current_stock` equal to 1 should have priority over a case where the `actual_stock` is 1 and the minimum among `current_stock` is 1000?

Comment: @trincot I see what you mean, I guess from focusing on two specific issues I've created a question that drives bad practice / bad logic. I may re-consider the approach with logic that makes more sense in stock management terms. For example weighting based on lowest stock / out of stock, then working up the hierarchy dealing with discrepencies between the two last, instead of mixing concerns.

Comment: Should I understand `current_stock` to be like a *need* for stock? I'm not sure how "current" has a different ring to it than "actual". Both mean the same thing to me... Can you explain in more detail what these concepts mean?

Comment: `current_stock` = the stock level the channel believes available, `actual_stock` = global stock available. This array dictates the priorities in which batch updates to stock on SKU's are applied. We want to prioritise certain situations. Overselling, is the number one priority we want to prevent that. Next we want to be sure that stock that is recorded as 0, when there is stock available, is pushed out as available. Finally ensure that stock levels across channels are as accurate as possible as our least concern. The main issues are overselling which needs to be stopped quickly.

Comment: So if the `actual_stock` is 0, shouldn't you need to look at the *maximum* among the `current_stock` instead of the minimum? What would be the reasoning to look at the minimum? I suppose the greater the maximum, the more urgent the issue is.

Comment: Valid question, I'll rework / rethink my reasoning and update the question or remove if no longer valid. I don't think I've thought this approach through thoroughly

Comment: I have still posted an answer. Maybe it is of use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this logic:

- To give a value to the risk of overselling, check if the *greatest* value among `current_stock` is greater than the actual stock. If so, give this risk a value of `log(max/actual_stock)` and 0 otherwise
- To give a value to the risk of under estimated stocks, check if the *least* value among `current_stock` is less than the actual stock. If so, give this risk a value of `log(actual_stock/min)` and 0 otherwise

Store these two risks as two extra properties, and use them in a `uasort` callback.

Here is suggested code:

```
function safeLog($a, $b) {
    return $b == 0 ? PHP_FLOAT_MAX : ($a > $b ? log($a / $b) : 0); 
}

function sign($n) {
    return ($n > 0) - ($n < 0);
}

foreach($stock_updates as &$a) {
    $low = min($a["current_stock"]);
    $high = max($a["current_stock"]);
    $a["overselling"] = safeLog($high, $a["actual_stock"]);
    $a["correction"] = safeLog($a["actual_stock"], $low);
}

uasort($stock_updates, function ($a, $b) {
    $res = sign($b["overselling"] - $a["overselling"]);
    if ($res == 0) $res = sign($b["correction"] - $a["correction"]);
    return $res;
});

print_r($stock_updates);
```

The output for the example will differ from yours, as this logic believes it is worse to have a *greatest* value of 1000 in `current_stock` -- when the actual is only 100 --  than that there is underestimation of 0 when actually stock is available (200).

You might have other ideas about the logic, but from this you can probably see how you can manipulate the formulas to your liking.

Comment: Just wanted to say a massive thanks for sticking through this yesterday, and raising some genuine questions to help reconsider logic, I'll put this to the test shortly, and will choose as the solution, thanks again